# How to have full page background image with semitrasparent effect with CSS?

Tags: css, background, size

i'm looking for a solution for having a full page background image with semitrasparent effect with CSS.
Looking in stackoverflow, i've found a solution for full page background image using:

```
background-image: url('background.jpg'); 
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
```

and one for semitrasparent effect using:

```
.watermark {
position:fixed;
}

.watermark:after {
    background: none no-repeat 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
    bottom: 0;
    content: " ";
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
```

but no one that solves both of them. 
How can i combine this two solutions?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why don't you just make a transparent background image and use that?

Comment: I tried, but I'm worse with photoshop than css... I don't succeed to replicate the same css effect in photoshop

Answer (score 0):

```
.image{
background-image: url('background.jpg'); 
background-size: cover;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
position:relative;
}
.watermark:after {
background-color:rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
content:"";
left: 0;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
height:100%;
width:100%;
}
```

Comment: In HTML, how can i position these two classes?
In my page I've thought to make:
<body class="watermark">
</body>
But the image class?